# Spark Structured Streaming with Protobuf Data Source and Evolving Schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, protocol-buffers

In Spark 3.4.0, Protobuf was supported as a data source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-protobuf.html

Looking through the documentation, it's not clear exactly how this behaves with structured streaming applications (or if that's even supported). Mainly, I'm curious how it works with a evolving descriptor file. Does the streaming query need to be restarted to rebuild from the provided descriptor file? Or is that done at the start of each batch within the query?

Ultimately, I'm wanting to know if it's going to pick up descriptor file changes without needing to restart the Spark application.